# VTK command line input

Tags: keyboard, command-line-interface, vtk

I'm wondering, what would be the best way to have a VTK-based program react to command line input by the user. Is there some built-in functionality to parse user input line by line after the VTK event loop is started?

I'm aware that I could catch key-press events and put command lines together character by character. This just doesn't sound like the easiest or most straight-forward way to me.

Is there a widget, I might be missing? E.g. like vtkTextWidget that allows text input rather than text output?

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing like that. You should just handle keypress events in your `vtkInteractorStyle` - here is one such example: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/KeypressEvents